# Dock window preview becomes too large when multiple instances of the same app is open

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell-extension

When multiple instances of the same app is opened, I get to see the preview of the opened instances. Before it was alright. Recently, it happened like this.

[image: Window preview]

Comment: Please explain how you got multiple instances of the macOS Finder app yo be open in Ubuntu with GNOME desktop environment to begin with.

Comment: mac os icon pack

Comment: nautilus file manager it is